# MUI Tree select - Set Value programatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Hi Im using this package, All working fine but I can't select a value by default programatically which is user selected already using same component .

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mikepricedev/mui-tree-select

Developer saying use this doc https://mikepricedev.github.io/mui-tree-select/interfaces/TreeSelectProps.html#value we can set, But I cant understand. Pls help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how to use a default value. I have changed [this source](https://codesandbox.io/s/smyzk?file=/src/App.js:0-4258) to have an initial value programatically. `value: "2:0"`

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import TreeSelect, { BranchNode, defaultInput } from "mui-tree-select";

const generateOptions = (parentBranch, randomAsync = true) => {
  const depth = parentBranch
    ? Number.parseInt(parentBranch.valueOf().label.split(":")[0]) + 1
    : 0;

  const options = [];

  for (let i = 0, len = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10); i < len; i++) {
    const option = `${depth}:${i}`;

    options.push(new BranchNode({ label: option }, parentBranch), option);
  }

  return randomAsync && Math.random() > 0.5
    ? new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(options);
        }, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000));
      })
    : options;
};

const getOptionLabel = (option) =>
  option instanceof BranchNode ? option.valueOf().label : option.toString();

const defaultBranch = BranchNode.createBranchNode([
  { label: "0:5" },
  { label: "1:2" }
]);

const Sample = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    single: {
      value: "2:0",
      options: generateOptions(defaultBranch, false),
      loading: false,
      branch: defaultBranch
    },
    multiple: {
      value: [],
      options: generateOptions(null, false),
      loading: false,
      branch: null
    }
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 350, padding: 16 }}>
      <TreeSelect
        branch={state.single.branch}
        onBranchChange={(_, branch) => {
          const options = generateOptions(branch);

          if (options instanceof Promise) {
            setState((state) => ({
              ...state,
              single: {
                ...state.single,
                branch,
                loading: true
              }
            }));
            options.then((options) => {
              setState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                single: {
                  ...state.single,
                  options,
                  loading: false
                }
              }));
            });
          } else {
            setState((state) => ({
              ...state,
              single: {
                ...state.single,
                branch,
                options,
                loading: false
              }
            }));
          }
        }}
        options={state.single.options}
        loading={state.single.loading}
        getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
        renderInput={useCallback(
          (params) =>
            defaultInput({
              ...params,
              variant: "outlined",
              label: "Single"
            }),
          []
        )}
        value={state.single.value}
        onChange={useCallback(
          (_, value) => {
            setState((state) => ({
              ...state,
              single: {
                ...state.single,
                value
              }
            }));
          },
          [setState]
        )}
      />
      <div style={{ height: "16px" }} />
      <TreeSelect
        onBranchChange={(_, branchOption) => {
          const options = generateOptions(branchOption);

          if (options instanceof Promise) {
            setState((state) => ({
              ...state,
              multiple: {
                ...state.multiple,
                loading: true
              }
            }));
            options.then((options) => {
              setState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                multiple: {
                  ...state.multiple,
                  options,
                  loading: false
                }
              }));
            });
          } else {
            setState((state) => ({
              ...state,
              multiple: {
                ...state.multiple,
                options,
                loading: false
              }
            }));
          }
        }}
        options={state.multiple.options}
        loading={state.multiple.loading}
        getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
        freeSolo
        multiple
        renderInput={useCallback(
          (params) =>
            defaultInput({
              ...params,
              variant: "outlined",
              label: "Multiple"
            }),
          []
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sample;
```

Comment: While open it should open and expand according to the value by default 
and if sets properly there will be path icon with tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have got solution, That you have to pass particular object with

```
     const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (defaultIndustries !== null) {
          setValue(() => new Node(defaultIndustries));
        }
      }, [defaultIndustries]);
```

And

```
 <TreeSelect
        getChildren={(node) =>
          syncOrAsync(
            node
              ? node.getChildren()
              : industryMultiTree.map((country) => new Node(country)),
            runAsync
          )
        }
        getOptionDisabled={(option) => {
          var _a;
          return (
            option.isBranch() &&
            !((_a = option.getChildren()) === null || _a === void 0
              ? void 0
              : _a.length)
          );
        }}
        getParent={(node) => syncOrAsync(node.getParent(), runAsync)}
        isBranch={(node) => syncOrAsync(node.isBranch(), runAsync)}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
          return option instanceof FreeSoloNode ? false : option.isEqual(value);
        }}
        value={value}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label={label}
            error={error}
            helperText={helperText}
          />
        )}
        sx={{ mb: 3 }}
        onChange={(_, value) => {
          onChangeSelect(value);
        }}
      />
```